# How can we implement page Object Model in Test complete

Tags: testcomplete

I am new to test complete and I looking to build BDD framework. I want to is it possible to create any page object model in test complete? How we have in selenium.

Any leads would be appreciated

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So, TestComplete creates it's own model of the application which works in a similar way to Page Object Model - you can find this in the Name Mapping section of your project. When you record routines in either a Keyword Test or script, TestComplete will automatically add page objects to the name mapping, alternatively you can add objects manually.

[image: Name Mapping for browser page objects]

You can then use Step Definitions to link Scenario steps to either Keyword Tests or script functions, e.g.

```
Given("some precondition", function (){
  KeywordTests.Test1.Run();
});
```